# Cannot connect to local SQL Server with SequelizeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect to my local SQL Server, but it shows an error SequelizeHostNotFoundError. I can connect with it on SSMS.

```
instance = new Sequelize('database', 'local123', 'local123', {
   host: "tcp:NETWORK-PC\\MYCOMPANYSQL,49172",
   dialect: 'mssql',
   port: 49172,
   operatorsAliases: false,
   dialectOptions: {
      options: {
          encrypt: true,
      }
   },
   pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
   },
})
```

> Errors: SequelizeHostNotFoundError: Failed to connect to tcp:NETWORK-PC\MYCOMPANYSQL,49172 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND tcp:NETWORK-PC\MYCOMPANYSQL,49172

Answer (score 0):

Local at what level? Have you tried "localhost" as a host?